# Woocommerce: filter available downloads according to meta data value in backend order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My ecommerce works like this: I have some downloadable products which have a list of files attached to it, available for downloads.

However I need to filter the downloads available according to the selection the user will make when adding to cart. These options are stored in order to filter the downloads available to the customers according to the selected options. So comparing the name of the download file against the strings in the array should do the trick.

I solved the Order part (see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77135577/woocommerce-filter-downloads-inside-the-order-according-to-meta-data-value) here): the right downloadable files are displayed in the **Order received page** and in the **email to the client**.

I still have problems in the **backend Order page** which still display all the files.

What are the right hooks and how can I retrieve the Array which stores the selected values?

Comment: That is 2 questions in one! The rule is one question at the time. So you need to choose between My Account > Downloads section or backend Single Order page.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I thought they could be controlled with the same filters. I edited the question...